# SQL lite combine Query

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I had written the following 3 queries.But need to combine all 3 of it to get final query.

Query 1:To get all the records between 2 dates.

```
  String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_ALL_RECORD_MAIN + " WHERE " + KEY_DATE + ">=" + fro + " AND " + KEY_DATE + "<=" + to + " OR " + OUTDATE + ">=" + fro + " AND " + KEY_OUTDATE + "<=" + to;
  SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
  Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
```

Query 2:To get all the records greater than "from_amount" and less than "to_amount".

```
  String selectQuery_amount = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_ALL_RECORD_MAIN + " WHERE " + KEY_AMOUNT + ">=" + from_amount + " AND " + KEY_AMOUNT + "<=" + to_amount;
  SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
  Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery_amount, null);
```

Query 3:To get all the records matching search_name.

```
  String selectQuery_amount = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_ALL_RECORD_MAIN + " WHERE " KEY_NAME + " like '" + search_name + "'";
  SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
  Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery_amount, null);
```

Reqiured Query :

1- to write query which combines all above queries.

e.g : To get all records from 04/05/2014 to 08/09/2015 with the amount 50000 to 60000 of user "Jack".

Comment: add `AND` between all the queries one after another after where clause. e.g- ... where condition1 AND conditionw and so on.

Answer (score 1):

```
  String selectQuery_amount = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_ALL_RECORD_MAIN +
  " WHERE " KEY_NAME + " ='" + search_name + "' AND "KEY_DATE 
  +" BETWEEN "+fro +" AND "+ to +" AND "+ KEY_AMOUNT +"BETWEEN "
  +from_amount +" AND "+to_amount;

  SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
  Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery_amount, null);

  //Date format would be like this  
  SELECT * FROM test WHERE date BETWEEN "2011-01-11" AND "2011-8-11"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine request using parenthesis `(`, `)` and `AND` word:

```
     String selectQuery =     "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_ALL_RECORD_MAIN + " WHERE " + 
//first query
" ( " + KEY_DATE + ">=" + fro + " AND " + KEY_DATE + "<=" + to + " OR " + OUTDATE + ">=" + fro + " AND " + KEY_OUTDATE + "<=" + to + " ) "
 + " AND " +
//second query
 " ( " + KEY_AMOUNT + ">=" + from_amount + " AND " + KEY_AMOUNT + "<=" + to_amount +  " ) "
+  " AND " +
//third query
" (  " + KEY_NAME + " like '" + search_name + "'" + " ) ";
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
```

and, of course, do not forget to use spaces correctly :)

Comment: In above query out of 4 integers (fro,to,from_amount,to_amount)  if any either is not it should return all records.I mean to say if i just pass name then it should return all the record by that name irrespective of date and amount

Comment: if i pass only two dates then it should return all record between that two dates irrespective of name and amount

Answer (score 0):

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_ALL_RECORD_MAIN + " WHERE "+
KEY_DATE + ">=" + fro + " AND " + KEY_DATE + "<=" + to + " OR " + OUTDATE + ">=" + fro + " AND " + KEY_OUTDATE + "<=" + to+"AND "+
KEY_AMOUNT + ">=" + from_amount + " AND " + KEY_AMOUNT + "<=" + to_amount+"AND "+
KEY_NAME + " like '" + search_name + "'";
SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
```

Note the `"AND "` keyword at the end of each line in the query which concatenates your querys. As a sidenote consider using `getReadableDatabase()` instead of `getWritableDatabase()` this is just a query, there is no reason to acquire a writeable instance in this case.